# How to integrate Elastic APM to Vuejs SPA?

Tags: vue.js, kibana, vue-router, elastic-stack, elastic-apm

I integrated `Elastic APM` as follows to my Vue.js App. It logs successfully to Elastic APM.

However it is not showing the current page name in logs correctly. It seems to always show the first page on which the App has been mounted in APM.

**I would like to always see the current page to be linked to the corresponding APM events.** Any suggestions how to achieve this?

The documentation says to set `pageLoadTransactionName`. However it seems to not update this on route change:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/current/custom-transaction-name.html

**App.js**

```
  mounted() {
    this.initializeApm();
  },
  methods: {
    initializeApm() {
      const currentPage =
        this.$route.name || window.location.href.split('#/')[1];
      // initialize elastic apm
      const apm = initApm({
        serviceName: this.config.apm.serviceName,
        serverUrl: this.config.apm.serverUrl,
        serviceVersion: this.config.version,
        pageLoadTransactionName: currentPage,
        distributedTracingOrigins: [
          'https://xxx.de',

        ],
        environment: this.config.stage
      });
      apm.setUserContext({
        id: this.getUserIdFromSession,
        username: this.getUserNameFromSession,
        email: this.getUserEmail
      });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When routing to a different subpage you have to set the Route Name manually. You can achieve this via a filter on the 'change-route' type. See `apm.addFilter()` 
docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/current/agent-api.html#apm-add-filter

Something like this should work:

```
apm.addFilter(payload => {
  if (payload.data) {
    const mappedData = [];
    payload.data.forEach(tr => {
      if (tr.type === 'route-change')
        mappedData.push({
          ...tr,
          name: this.$route.name // overwrite unknown with the current route name
        });
      else mappedData.push(tr);
    });
    payload.data = mappedData;
  }
  return payload;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be to observe for transaction events which is fired whenever transaction starts and ends.

```
// on transaction start
apm.observe("transaction:start", transaction => {

});

// on transaction end
apm.observe("transaction:end", transaction => {

});
```

API docs - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/current/agent-api.html#observe

The agent also supports frameworks such as Vue.js, React and Angular out of the box, so the above code should not be necessary.

Vue docs - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/rum-js/current/vue-integration.html